# What is the mechanism for converting a function to a trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, actix-web

An [example from actix-web](https://actix.rs/docs/application/) is as follows:

```
use actix_web::{web, App, Responder, HttpServer};

async fn index() -> impl Responder {
    "Hello world!"
}

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new().service(
            web::scope("/app").route("/index.html", web::get().to(index)),
        )
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8088")?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

**My question is around how the statement `to(index)` works in Rust.**

Looking at the [source code for `to`](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/74491dca59b3173f75fda2799ee7a44c755866a1/src/route.rs#L226) we see:

```
pub fn to<F, T, R, U>(mut self, handler: F) -> Self
where
    F: Factory<T, R, U>,
// --- snip
```

Where [`Factory` is defined as](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/74491dca59b3173f75fda2799ee7a44c755866a1/src/handler.rs#L19):

```
pub trait Factory<T, R, O>: Clone + 'static
where
    R: Future<Output = O>,
    O: Responder,
{
    fn call(&self, param: T) -> R;
}
```

**What is the mechanism by which the function `async fn index() -> impl Responder` gets converted to `Factory<T, R, O>`?**

Comment: This is, indeed, a good question. I'm expectating.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is [an implementation of the trait](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/74491dca59b3173f75fda2799ee7a44c755866a1/src/handler.rs#L27) just after your snippet:

```
impl<F, R, O> Factory<(), R, O> for F
where
    F: Fn() -> R + Clone + 'static,
    R: Future<Output = O>,
    O: Responder,
{
    fn call(&self, _: ()) -> R {
        (self)()
    }
}
```

This can be read as: if a type `F` implements `Fn() -> Future<Output = impl Responder> + ...` then it also implements `Factory<(), _, _>`.

And an `async fn` is syntactic sugar for a function which returns a `Future` of some sort (and can use `.await` internally), so `async fn index() -> impl Responder` implements `Fn() -> impl Future<Output = impl Responder>` so it also implements `Factory<(), _, _>`.

Comment: Also lingo correction: there is no *conversion* in the code posted, instead there is a *constraint*: `F` needs to implement the specified trait, but its identity doesn't change.